# Returning nth Word in the Line Using a Generator Function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looking for assistance as I have been trying many for a couple of nights to no avail. I am trying to create a generator function that will return the nth word in the line from a file. For this example, I will be looking for the 3rd word. I had tried both below:

```
def nth_of_each_line(mypath):
    with open (mypath, 'r') as my_file:
        for line in my_file:
            line = line.strip()
            word = line.split()[3]
            yield word

def nth_of_each_line(mypath):
    with open (mypath, 'r') as my_file:
        for line in my_file:
            line = line.strip()
            word = line.split()
            yield word[3]

mypath = 'Test.txt'
for x in nth_of_each_line(mypath):
    print(x)
```

I receive list index out of range and I tried moving the yield line in different places. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Also, if the line is short (has 2 words but we are looking for the third), it will return default value None.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what if the file contains lines with less than 4 words? test that before accessing the 4th word.

Comment: are the 2 function name same?

Comment: those are 2 attempts

Comment: `[3]` is getting the fourth word.

Comment: can you share the `text` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just protect access to return `None` when line is too short (add a parameter to make your function generic):

```
def nth_of_each_line(mypath,n):
    with open (mypath, 'r') as my_file:
        for line in my_file:
            word = line.split()   # no need for strip as split discards end of line already
            yield word[n] if len(word)>n else None
```

note that lists are zero indexed so using `n=3` returns the 4th word.

You can optimize slightly with `word = line.split(None,n)` to stop splitting after the nth item (you don't need the last split tokens).